# Bending loop effect with Simulation Nodes

Tags: geometry-nodes, simulation-nodes

I try to animate a simple and lightweight leave wind movement, for a complete tree.

I use Geometry Nodes to scatter leaves on branches, and a geometry node on the trunk mesh to scatter branches.

I actually try to use geometry nodes with a simulation zone to bend each leaves in a loop.

I managed to have a functional node setup, that you can see here :[image]

But this node setup actually bend the leave continuously and I need it to be reversed each x frames, like each 30 frames for example.

Like this, the leave bend in the X direction, then after 30 frames, start to bend in the -X direction.

How can I achieve this ?

Here is the blend file (only one leave) : [image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

do you mean like this?

just add a ping pong (math node) and a subtract node like this:

[image]

result:

[image]

the "trick" is here to just adjust the frame so that you get the right values. Like -30 to 30 in your case here.

Comment: Amazing ! Thanks ! that's exactly what i want !